# How to cover a sector (widening ray, cone etc.) with equidistant points (chess tiles pattern)?

Tags: javascript, java, c#, algorithm, geometry

Suppose there's an origin point s=(x,y) and two angles a and b. The angles create a ray, light cone from the point p. I'd like to obtain a list of points that are within that area and are on the same distance from each other vertically and horizontally. The maximum distance is theoretically infinite (but restricted by something else not considered in this algorithm).

[image]

I've tried recursive method and it worked for wider angles. For acute angles, the number of adjacent squares had to increase so that failed. I've tried following one of the lines described by the angles and counting all the dots inside the angles vertically placed. That failed due to vertical lines and got very messy due to different quadrants etc. I tried to brute force double for-loop but that dies due to excess of the stupid points when I increased granularity.

I need help to reformulate the problem in a way so it's more approachable. I code the solution in C# but, obviously, the issue is technology agnostic so anything will do.

Comment: Treat each quadrant separately; take unions of points if the rays are in different quadrants. When both rays are in the same quadrant, either (i) they're both <= 45 degrees, (ii) both > 45 degrees, or (iii) one is below and one is above 45 degrees. For (i), push Bresenham's algorithm rightwards along the x axis to find, for each x, the bottommost and topmost y point between the two rays.  For (ii) do likewise, but proceed upwards along the y axis. For (iii), draw a third ray c at exactly 45 degrees, solve subproblems for ray pairs (a, c) and (b, c) and form the union. (Might be faster ways.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For angles `A` and `B` in range `-Pi/2..Pi/2` and `B>A` consider the next approach:
Let's ray starting point is `(x0, y0)`.

Then vertical grid line with coordinate `x1` will contain grid points inside sector that have y-coordinates in range

```
  Ceil(y0 + (x1-x0) * tg(A)) .. Floor(y0 + (x1-x0) * tg(B))
```

`Ceil` is rounding up, `Floor` is rounding down (this Y-range could be empty)

This approach works for angles in range `Pi/2..3Pi/2`, if we exchange angles. And for angles in different semi-planes, if we divide sector by x0 vertical into 2 parts.
Another way - use horizontal scanlines instead of vertical ones for some orientations.

Comment: What about cases when the cone goes vertically? Or if it gets on two quadrants (say between lines -1,1 and 1,1)? It all gets very messy pretty quickly. I sense that there should be a simle solution **if** I approach the problem from another angle (angle, get it, hehe)...

Comment: As I said, divide such cone with vertical axis. (1,1)-(-1,1) should give  (1,1)-(0,1) and (0,1)-(-1,1). You can consider also horizontal scanlines instead of vertical for such cone orientation. Note- it is rather simple solution, it gives whole ranges of coordinates.

Comment: I see now how you mean. It gets so iffy and elsy pretty quickly, hehe. And, of course, since I deal with doubles I'll need to take that into account (instead of flooring I'll have to round it to a certain multiple of something). I guess it's just a nasty problem so it'll require a nastly solution. Thanks, friend!

Answer (score 0):

The idea would be to formulate cone as to lines defined by equations:

line1: A1x+B1y+C1=0

line2: A2x+B2y+C2=0

That means any point that belongs to a line satisfy its equation.
And points laying above give positive result, laying below - negative.

The point you are looking for are let's say below line1 and above line2 ... and on some grid.

Comment: What do you mean? The only additional requiremet the lines are not pararell to create a cone. With those two lines you got in fact 4 cones. To choose one of them you have add contraint for required sign of line formula.